# How to insert each object from the array of objects into the corresponding object in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, object

This thing is easy, so please give me a reference if there is one or answer.
I have a array of different non-repeatable objects, e.g

```
object[] data { Cat, Dog, Bird };
```

So I need to insert each object from the array into the corresponding object.
Something like this :

```
Cat cat = data.Select(x => (Cat)x).FirstOrDefault();
Dog dog = data.Select(x=>(Dog)x).FirstOrDefault();
.
.
.
```

I tried :

```
using System.Linq;

Cat cat = data.Select(x => (Cat)x).FirstOrDefault();
Dog dog = data.Select(x=>(Dog)x).FirstOrDefault();
```

and this :

```
Cat cat = (Cat)data.Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
```

but I only got :

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'
```

Comment: iterate `data` and use pattern matching(or simple usage of `is` operator) inside loop

Comment: `data.OfType<Cat>().FirstOrDefault()`. More elegant is iterating the collection only once instead of once per each type, per Selvin -- but then you'll have to loop explicitly, LINQ isn't going to help you.

Comment: ^^ Like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ITFTEc

Comment: I'd argue that these objects shouldn't be held in one list to begin with. But sometimes, you cannot avoid it, I guess.

Comment: thank you for your quick answers, @JeroenMostert  your answer suits me best

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
using System.Linq;

Cat myCat = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Cat)) as Cat;
Dog myDog = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Dog)) as Dog;
```

Read about [Object.GetType Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-7.0) and [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-7.0)

**EDIT:**

As the comment by @Klaus points it won't work with subclasses, in that case you can use [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-7.0)

```
Cat myCat = data.OfType<Cat>().FirstOrDefault();
Dog myDog = data.OfType<Dog>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Drawbacks: `myCat` and `myDog`  are still of type `object`. And it does not work with subclasses of `cat` and `Dog`.

Comment: I agree with @KlausGütter , a specified cast of object is necessary

Answer (score 1):

By using @FortyTwo's answer, you can also create a generic extension method to get the first object of a specific type from the object array.

```cs
public static class ObjectArrExtensions
{
    public static TValue? GetFirstObjectOf<TValue>(this IEnumerable<object> objects) where TValue : class
    { 
        return objects.OfType<TValue>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Results in:

```cs
object[] objects = { Cat, Dog }
var dog = objects.GetFirstObjectOf<Cat>();
```